# Browsers does not reflects updates in the code

Tags: html, css

While working on HTML, CSS (and more) like changing the code and refreshing the browser, after updating the files (local or remote [ftp]) and refreshing the browser won't reflect the changes.

Many browses suffer from this problem. Firefox, Safari and even Opera (Opera GX); any updates or changes to the remote or local files won't be reflected. **This problem is not new, it's been around for decades!**

Even if I upload the new file to the server and refresh in FF it is not showing the new code styles, I have emptied cookies. I am confused; any ideas?

Comment: Sometimes CTRL-F5 does the trick, or try clearing your browser's cache. If that doesn't work, does renaming the HTML document work? Regardless, this should not be a problem - I think Chrome and Firefox are both smart enough to read timestamps of local files to see if they've been modified since they were last loaded.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Maybe you're modifying a different file. It happens.

Comment: I have done this before. Accidentally renamed the file and not noticed. Palm --> face!

Comment: In my case, I was modifying a similarly named file - ON A DIFFERENT PROJECT! Spent a good number of minutes figuring out what was wrong with my code when there was none.

Comment: Thank you everyone so much for the input, Im installing the developer addon now, and force clearing the cache worked. Thanks!

Comment: This solved it for me

Answer (score 30):

Try refreshing with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>

That will empty the browser's cache and refresh the page.

Comment: Great the easiest solution, Thanks

Comment: THANK YOU!!!! It works. I have headaches over this problem when dev'ing

Comment: cant tell all clients.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to get around this is to press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>. The ctrl modifier (supported by most/all modern browsers) forces a full reload of the page.

Answer (score 3):

Or shift+click on the refresh button

Comment: As a long-term web-page developer, my 2-cents worth: Ignore those who claim: "Can NOT reproduce". OF COURSE you will often NOT be able to reproduce. Each condition and symptom might have different underlying causes, and many are browser-specific (so the reporter could have tried to reproduce only on his/her favorite browser). .

Comment: This 'Hold-down SHIFT-KEY/hit-Reload-button' worked for the one specific case that I was having. (Worked in Chrome browser.)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your server is sending the correct caching information for the file. If it doesn't tell the browser correctly that the file is outdated, the browsers won't download it again.

See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching for a good overview.

Comment: "Make sure your server is sending the correct caching information for the file." How to do it?

Comment: @klm123 See my edits.

Comment: thanks, but this overview has a lot of information and doesn't look specific enough for this problem. If you meant to simply add "<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache">" to index.html - it doesn't help.

Comment: @klm123 I specifically didn't mean that. The document is so long and complex because there are now a ton of different places where caching is done, so you have to work through all the points and check each of them until you find the culprit. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

Are you going through a proxy server? Often these can cache files.

Otherwise, check browser settings:

In IE7 go to Tools > General > Browsing History Settings and select 'Everytime' for the 'Check for new pages' option.

Answer (score 2):

When using Firefox I would install the Web Developer extension https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60 which is a really good tool for forcing cache to empty.

Comment: Now a days you can use *Disable Cache* in Network of your browser console.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem
and I did all the above suggestions
But my problem was not resolved
next I checked from inspector that the file was read from cache memory or no
answer was no, at the end I found that my php version is 5.4, problem solved after change php version to ver 7

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl+F5 should properly refresh the page
This also works for python eel library not updating refreshing straight away after changes

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a very old topic, but Firefox still fails to show code changes after refreshing a page, then viewing the page source.  What works for me is when I "View Page Source" in Firefox, I then refresh the newly-opened tab which contains the page source.

Comment: It’s fine to answer old questions. The person who asked has long since solved their problem, but there will be thousands more who arrive here by searching.

Comment: @TomZych Except in cases where the question is not on-topic, in which case we should not be answering it but rather flagging/voting for closure.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. That's because of the browser cache. Better clear the cache and refresh the page. I use a private window or icognito as in Chrome so its not cached. Make the change and refresh the page. Your changes should have been reflected.

Answer (score 0):

You also can load your style using direct url and then press ctrl+r (ctrl+f5) to refresh it.